# Getting Undefined error while playing song from facebook wall

Tags: facebook, api, rest

I publish music on Facebook wall through my application (demosrbt) by using following api.

`https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish`

Its got published successfully on wall. But I am getting **undefined** error, while playing song from wall.

attachment format is

```
{"media": [{"type": "mp3", "src": "http://onspire.onmobile.com/srbt/preview/IDEA_IND/1/6/b/rbt_testclip363_preview.mp3", "title": "title Testing", "artist": "artist Testing", "album": "Testing"}]}`
```

In embed, src has long value, instead of path

```
<embed width="300" height="29" flashvars="audio_log=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Fapplications%2Fmusicplayer%2Faudio_listen_log.php&amp;show_title=1&amp;fbt_artist=By&amp;fbt_title=Title&amp;fbt_album=Album&amp;fbt_unavailable=Unavailable&amp;src=***1b4419434e4753010941030a0025430d025e1c52045f11461f010a1d0011103442121e56055908445b21382b266d3a2d366f5c4d5a1c111f1f510037080b1446100f1b305e545f6c034208451d0d0b400a4240***&amp;song=Test+Clip363&amp;artist=test+artist363&amp;album=testa+lbum363&amp;width=300&amp;height=29&amp;user=100001643190330&amp;log=no&amp;showErrors=no&amp;div_id=id_4e92f084dfd897660119695&amp;swf_id=swf_id_4e92f084dfd897660119695&amp;browser=Firefox+3.6&amp;post_form_id=a98ccdcf8d075cd10c42139c777402fa&amp;string_table=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fflash_strings.php%2Ft91545%2Fen_US" wmode="opaque" scale="noscale" salign="tl" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="swf_id_4e92f084dfd897660119695" id="swf_id_4e92f084dfd897660119695" style="" src="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/y2/r/JvWzcSQ5kI0.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

thanks in advance, to give solutions for the same.